# Null pointer exception spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to pass values to the persistence layer in a springboot application using jpa. However, each time I get a null pointer exception despite that I see that the object to be persisted is well formed. I have my code snippets below.

**AlertRepository**

```
public interface AlertRepository extends JpaRepository<Alert, Integer>{
 }
```

**AlertController**

```
@Controller
public class AlertController {

@Autowired
private AlertRepository alertRepository;    
@GetMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY GET Requests
public @ResponseBody String addNewAlert (@RequestParam Alert cAlert) {
    Alert alert = new Alert();
    alert.setAlert(cAlert.getAlert());
    alert.setAttack(cAlert.getAttack());
    alertRepository.save(alert);

    .....
    .....
    return "Saved";
}
```

**Get_Save_Alert**

```
ApiResponse hh = zapClient.core.numberOfAlerts(target);
        List<Alert> alertList = zapClient.getAlerts(target, 0, 0);
        // zapClient.core.alerts(target, start, count);
        System.out.println("the number of alerts is : " + hh);
        de.cavas.model.Alert cavasAlert = new de.cavas.model.Alert();
        for (Alert alert : alertList) {
            cavasAlert.setRisk(alert.getRisk().toString());
            cavasAlert.setConfidence(alert.getConfidence().toString());
            cavasAlert.setUrl((alert.getUrl().toString()));
            cavasAlert.setParam(alert.getParam().toString());
            cavasAlert.setSolution(alert.getSolution());
            cavasAlert.setCweid(String.valueOf(alert.getCweId()));
            cavasAlert.setWascid(String.valueOf(alert.getWascId()));
            cavasAlert.setAttack(alert.getAttack());
            cavasAlert.setDescription(alert.getDescription());
            cavasAlert.setName(alert.getName());
            cavasAlert.setPluginId(alert.getPluginId());
            cavasAlert.setReference(alert.getReference());


            controller.addNewAlert(cavasAlert);
            }
```

Here is the exception stacktrace:

```
Exception : null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.cavas.repository.AlertController.addNewAlert(AlertController.java:26)
at de.cavas.SecurityTest.preRegistrationTest(SecurityTest.java:281)
at 
de.cavas.InstanceRegistry.handleTempRegistration(InstanceRegistry.java:250)
at de.cavas.InstanceRegistry.register(InstanceRegistry.java:155)
```

Line 26 in the trace refers to  the line  `alertRepository.save(alert)` in the `AlertController Class`.

**Update**
I have also provided the application.yml file incase there is something "fishy" I cannot see !

```
server:
port: 8761
eureka:
    client:
          registerWithEureka: false
         fetchRegistry: false
server:
      waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0    
spring:
   datasource:
       url: jdbc:mysql://sssss:500/vulncorrelate?useSSL=false
   username: ss
   password: ss
   platform: mysql
   initialize: false
 jpa:
   database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   generate-ddl: true
   spring.jpa.show-sql: true
   hibernate.ddl-auto: update
```

**update 2** - the `Alert` entity class

```
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

public class Alert {

String microserviceName;
String microservicePort;
String microserviceIpAddress;
String microserviceId;
String timeStamp;

@JsonProperty("sourceid")
private String sourceid;


@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty("other")
private String other;

@JsonProperty("method")
private String method;

@Lob
@JsonProperty("evidence")
private String evidence;

@JsonProperty("pluginId")
private String pluginId;

@JsonProperty("cweid")
private String cweid;

@JsonProperty("confidence")
private String confidence;

@JsonProperty("wascid")
private String wascid;

@JsonProperty("description")
private String description;

@JsonProperty("messageId")
private String messageId;

@Lob
@JsonProperty("url")
private String url;

@Lob
@JsonProperty("reference")
private String reference;

@JsonProperty("solution")
private String solution;

@Lob
@JsonProperty("alert")
private String alert;

@Lob
@JsonProperty("param")
private String param;

@Lob
@JsonProperty("attack")
private String attack;
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("risk")
private String risk;
@JsonProperty("id")
private int id;

@JsonProperty("sourceid")
public String getSourceid() {
    return sourceid;
}

public Alert(String microserviceName, String microservicePort, String 
microserviceIpAddress, String microserviceId,
        String timeStamp, String sourceid, String other, String method, 
String evidence, String pluginId,
        String cweid, String confidence, String wascid, String description, 
String messageId, String url,
        String reference, String solution, String alert, String param, 
String attack, String name, String risk,
        int id) {
    super();
    this.microserviceName = microserviceName;
    .....
}

public Alert() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

...... //setters and getters
 }
```

Comment: Would be nice to tell us in which line you get the NPE.. By the way, it is called **exception**, not exemption

Comment: The stacktrace is still quite useless unless you tell us which line is line 26...

Comment: Spring will never autowire static fields. That's why it's null, and that's why you get a NullPointerException.

Comment: @user3237736 line 26 is in the AlertController Class the line "   alertRepository.save(alert);"

Comment: So that means `alertRepository` is `null` (autowiring failed). How did you autowire it? Btw why is it `static`?

Comment: @user3237736 I guess a habit from conventional java ... even after removing the "static" keyword, I still have the exception. Is there another way to approach this ?

Comment: weird habit for "conventional java" to make fields static. 99% of java variables are usually non-static. well anyways, how did you configure Spring?

Comment: yeah, I am using `application.yml` file and the db connection information is specified there. Or what do you mean by how it is configured ?

Comment: a Spring `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` as that wouldn't allow your application to start. That being said, injection into `static` fields will never work so remove `static`. The fact that your field is `null` makes me believe you are creating a new instance of your controller instead of letting spring create and manage an instance for you. Judging from your snippet of stacktrace you are trying to test things either without using Spring or without providing a proper mocked implementation (when doing plain unit testing). In short the error is probably in your `SecurityTest`.

Comment: Also what is the use of an `@Controller` if you are calling it directly like a `service`? Looking a bit closer at your stacktrace also looks like you are using a service locator instead of letting Spring wire things together.

Comment: @M. Deinum thanks for your answers. I am not testing but running the application directly. The application is originally cloned from `https://github.com/dsyer/eureka`, and the security testing part is my own modification. My motive is to test for security vulnerabilities that might exist in the services the send registration requests.

Comment: So you are actually testing, that is pretty clear from the stacktrace you added. The problem is your `SecurityTest` class as that isn't using Spring Boot (although you might think it does).

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes the security testing runs inclusively ... can you offer some possible solutions ? The approach I previously used was to send the test results to another spring_jpa application which handled persistence. I though it is possible to include the logic in the `eureka` application i.e. more straight-forward. What are your suggestions for overcoming this hurdle ?

Comment: Judging from your stacktrace you are trying to work around Spring (service locator, doing looks etc) and judging further you are creating new instances of bean yourself inside the `SecurityTest`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169078/discussion-between-sycode-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
private AlertRepository alertRepository;
```

and 
    On your main application class
add
**@EnableAutoConfiguration**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also  if you are not using @Repository then spring will never create bean for your repo, In that case it will throw nullPointer exception

```
  @Repository 
    public interface AlertRepository extends
     JpaRepository<Alert, Integer>{  }
```

Comment: Why don't I see @Repository used on to of your repository.

Comment: Also can you also add Alert model here ?

Comment: I used the annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories`, do I need to use `Repository` also ? I will update with the `Alert` pojo asap

Comment: yea   @Repository 
    public interface AlertRepository extends
     JpaRepository<Alert, Integer>{  }

Comment: You do have this table created correct, under your schema of db?  I don't see any hibernate mapping there.

Comment: yeah, I thought `@Entity` should be fine ? ... additional configuration is in the `application.yml` file.

Comment: It dependents how you are doing it. here is one of the way to map https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm

Comment: I followed the`xml-less` option in this tutorial  - http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa

Comment: I understand, It should work if your model properties like microserviceName is one of the column if that column name it self is microserviceName. otherwise if you check the video at 3:25 it also maps the column, Also you need to define primary key using @Id also generation type if applicable. Also check that what all the fields are not null, You have to pass those to save the record

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing these two points

1. Have you added **@EnableJpaRepositories** annotation or xml configuration to enable Spring-data repository support.
   Xml configuration like - `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories"/>`.

2 I think you should remove static keyword from Repository Autowiring and make it private if it is used in only this clas, for instance

```
@Autowired
private AlertRepository alertRepository;
```

Comment: I have done added `@EnableJpaRepositories` and taken out the `static` keyword ...but no joy yet !